# Erlang Dialyzer: only accept certain integers?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

Say I have a function,`foo/1`, whose spec is `-spec foo(atom()) -> #r{}.`, where `#r{}` is a record defined as `-record(r, {a :: 1..789}).`, however, I have `foo(a) -> 800.` in my code, when I run dialyzer against it, it didn't warn me about this, (`800` is not a "valid" return value for function `foo/1`), can I make dialyzer warn me about this?

**Edit**

[Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer) says:

> Dialyzer reserves the right to expand this range into a bigger one.

But I couldn't find how to disable this.

Comment: `foo(a)` would not be affected by the type spec for record `r`, since it just accepts an atom as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

As of Erlang 18, the handling of integer ranges is done by `erl_types:t_from_range/2`. As you can [see](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/fe1df7fc6bf050cb6c9bbd99eb9393c426b62f67/lib/hipe/cerl/erl_types.erl#L1974), there are a lot of generalizations happening to get a "safe" overapproximation of a range.

If you tried to `?USE_UNSAFE_RANGES` (see the code) it is likely that your particular error would be caught, but at a terrible cost: native compilation and dialyzing of recursive integer functions would not ever finish!

The reason is that the type analysis for recursive functions uses a simple fixpoint approach, where the initial types accept the base cases and are repeatedly expanded using the recursive cases to include more values. At some point overapproximations must happen if the process is to terminate. Here is a concrete example:

```
fact(1) -> 1;
fact(N) -> N * fact(N - 1).
```

Initially `fact/1` is assumed to have type `fun(none()) -> none()`. Using that to analyse the code, the second clause is 'failing' and only the first one is ok. Therefore after the first iteration the new type is `fun(1) -> 1`. Using the new type the second clause can succeed, expanding the type to `fun(1|2) -> 1|2`. Then `fun(1|2|3) -> 1|2|6` this continues until the `?SET_LIMIT` is reached in which case `t_from_range` stops using the individual values and type becomes `fun(1..255) -> pos_integer()`. The next iteration expands `1..255` to `pos_integer()` and then `fun(pos_integer()) -> pos_integer()` is a fixpoint!

Incorrect answer follows (explains the first comment below):

<s>You should get a warning for this code if you use the `-Woverspecs` option. This option is not enabled by default, since Dialyzer operates under the assumption that it is 'ok' to over-approximate the return values of a function. In your particular case, however, you actually want any extra values to produce warnings.</s>

Comment: actually it won't. if the range is small, say `1..3` and you return `4`, dialyzer will warn you even if you don't specify `-Woverspecs`, however if the range is large, dialyzer won't warn you even if you specify `-Woverspecs`.